# How to make ViewModel - View interface more clear?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Imagine a view model `SomeViewModel` used by `SomeView`:

```
public class SomeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public NumberEditorViewModel VoltageEditor { get; private set; }

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        VoltageEditor = new NumberEditorViewModel(...) { ... }
    }
}
```

which uses a reusable sub- view model for editing all numbers, something like:

```
public class NumberEditorViewModel: BindableBase
{
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

So the view can use it like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding VoltageEditor.Title} />
    <TextBox Text={Binding VoltageEditor.Value} />
    <TextBlock Text={Binding VoltageEditor.Unit} />
</StackPanel>
```

These properties - `Title`, `Value`, `Unit` are what the view is going to access.

But in reality the `NumberEditorViewModel` is a complicated class, provides unit conversion (metric / imperial), formats values so they have proper precision (format strings) etc. For this reason it has a whole bunch of properties to specify what unit it uses, what kind of precision is required etc., so it can format and parse the value properly. They would be set in `SomeViewModel`, like:

```
VoltageEditor = new NumberEditorViewModel()
{
    Title = "My Voltage:",
    UnitType = UnitType.Voltage,
    PrecisionType = PrecisionType.SomePrecision,
    ...
}
```

This makes `NumberEditorViewModel` model messy, because it has a lot of properties and nobody knows which of them are to be used by the view, and which  are to be used by the creator of this object to control its behavior.

How can I improve this to make for more clear interface between the view and the view model, and also between this view model and its creator?

I tried using an interface to only give a subset of properties to the view, but WPF seems to ignore that and use whatever is available on the object for binding. And this also kills view-model-first approach.

Comment: You could pass view model another object like `NumberViewModelConfig` but having a hard time seeing this as a problem... Who cares that the view has to know which properties to bind to? It is unavoidable since each binding has to specify a property so an interface or anything else seems like just more work for not much gain. Maybe just some good documentation is the answer here.

Comment: Pass properties that control behavior in constructor instead?

Comment: @Evk this is what I an doing now, but the constructor gets ~10 parameters at this point and it's growing - it gets messy. Not to mention you can't change them later.

Comment: @blins it's like you would say *who needs private and protected...*

Comment: Then create separate class, group all such parameters there and pass instance of that class to constructor, not each parameter individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse me asking first, and then answering on my own, I'm feeling bad doing this. But maybe it helps someone.

I think I was having a design problem there, which resulted in too much stuff being put into the view model. The cleanest solution seems to be to extract all this functionality to a separate (logical) object. And then having the view model (numeric sub-view model) as a very simple object, which takes the logical object in the constructor. I think @Evk was suggesting something similar (thanks), but without moving all the logic.

If it is needed to further change the behavior (ie. make something read only), it is done by changing properties on the logical object.

The only properties on the view model are now these needed by the view.

At the end, it looks like this (excuse me complications in the code but these are real production code excerpts now, for better understanding).

Logical object:

```
public class RealParameter<T> : BindableBase2 where T : struct
{
    private readonly IUnitService _unitService;
    private readonly IValueProvider<T> _valueProvider;
    private readonly IValueReceiver<T> _valueReceiver;
    private readonly IValueProvider<bool> _canUseProvider;
    private bool _canUseOverride = true;
    private readonly IValueProvider<bool> _readOnlyProvider;
    private bool _readOnlyOverride = false;
    private UnitType _unitType;
    private PrecisionType _precisionType;
    private string _customFormatString;
    private string _customUnitString;

    public RealParameter(
        IUnitService unitService,
        IValueProvider<T> valueProvider,
        IValueReceiver<T> valueReceiver = null,
        UnitType unitType = UnitType.None,
        PrecisionType precisionType = default(PrecisionType),
        IValueProvider<bool> canUseProvider = null,
        IValueProvider<bool> readOnlyProvider = null)
    {
        _unitService = unitService;
        _valueProvider = valueProvider;
        ...
    }

    public UnitType UnitType
    {
        get { return _unitType; }
        set
        {
            _unitType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public PrecisionType PrecisionType
    {
        get { return _precisionType; }
        set
        {
            _precisionType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get ...
        set ...
    }

    public T LocalValue
    {
        // unit conversion goes here
        get ...
        set ...
    }

    [DependsOn(nameof(LocalValue))]
    [DependsOn(nameof(CustomFormatString))]
    [DependsOn(nameof(PrecisionType))]
    public string LocalValueDisplay
    {
        // formatting to / parsing from a string goes here
        get ...
        set ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Numeric view model:

```
public class RealParameterVm<T> : BindableBase2 where T : struct
{
    private readonly RealParameter<T> _parameter;
    private readonly string _title;

    public RealParameterVm(RealParameter<T> parameter, string title = null)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
        _title = title;

        _parameter.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(_parameter.LocalValueDisplay))
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));

            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(_parameter.UnitDisplay))
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Unit));

            ...
        };
    }

    public string Title => _title;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _parameter.LocalValueDisplay; }
        set { _parameter.LocalValueDisplay = value; }
    }

    public string Unit => _parameter.UnitDisplay;

    public string ValueAndUnit => _parameter.LocalValueAndUnitDisplay;

    public bool CanUse => _parameter.CanUse;

    public bool IsReadOnly => _parameter.IsReadOnly;

    public T NumericGlobal => _parameter.Value;

    public T NumericLocal => _parameter.LocalValue;
}
```

And usage in the main view model of the view:

```
public class SomeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IPlcService _plc;
    private readonly IUnitService _unitService;
    public RealParameterVm<double> Distance { get; }

    public SomeViewModel(IPlcService plc, IUnitService unitService)
    {
        _plc = plc;
        _unitService = unitService;

        Distance = new RealParameterVm<double>(new RealParameter<double>(
            _unitService,
            _plc.Main.Interface.HmiDev.Distance,
            _plc.Main.Interface.HmiDev.DistanceCanUse,
            _plc.Main.Interface.HmiDev.DistanceIsReadOnly,
            UnitType.Distance_mm,
            PrecisionType.Position
            ), "Some distance:");
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsEnabled="{Binding Distance.CanUse}">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Distance.Title} />
    <TextBox Text={Binding Distance.Value} IsReadOnly="{Binding Distance.IsReadOnly}" />
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Distance.Unit} />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea, instead of using an Interface to give a subset of properties, you could use subclasses as adapters.

Each subclass could be given by a getter by your NumberEditorViewModel.

Something like this:

```
public class NumberEditorViewModel
{
    // quick & dirty
    public SubTypeA ExampleA { get { return new SubTypeA ( this ); } }
    public SubTypeB ExampleB { get { return new SubTypeB ( this ); } }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text={Binding VoltageEditor.ExampleA.Title} />
    <TextBox Text={Binding VoltageEditor.ExampleA.Value} />
    <TextBlock Text={Binding VoltageEditor.ExampleA.Unit} />
</StackPanel>
```

- Edit -

(1) We tend to use nested classes for this kind of thing, but it's just a matter of preference.

(2) Here's an approch that will raise the propertychanged event between subtypes:

You can leverage the PropertyChanged event to communicate between viewmodels as they are closely related to each others.

```
public class NumberEditorViewModel : BindableBase
{
    // subtypes ///////////////////////////////

    public class SubTypeA
    {
        public string PrecisionType 
        {
            get { return _precisionType; } 
            set { _precisionType = value; OnPropertyChanged ( ); }
        }
        private string _precisionType;
    }

    public class SubTypeB
    {
        public string INPC 
        {
            get { return _inpc; } 
            set { _inpc = value; OnPropertyChanged ( ); }
        }
        private string _inpc;
    }

    // ctor ///////////////////////////////

    public NumberEditorViewModel ( )
    {
        ExampleA = new SubTypeA ( );
        ExampleB = new SubTypeB ( );

        ExempleA.PropertyChanged += ( sender, e ) =>
        {
            if ( e.PropertyName == nameof ( SubTypeA.PrecisionType ) )
            {
                var exempleA = sender as ExempleA;

                ExampleB.INPC = ... /* newValue calculated */
            }
        }
    }

    public SubTypeA ExampleA { get; private set; }
    public SubTypeB ExampleB { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like some idea. Additional step in the binding path is some disadvantage, but maybe acceptable. Questions I have: (1) are SubTypeX nested classes or just normal types? (2) let's say someone changes `SubTypeA.PrecisionType` property. How do I raise `INPC.PropertyChanged` on `SubTypeB.Value`?

Comment: Ended up fixing a design (see another answer) but upvoted this one.

Comment: Thanks ! Glad you could figure something out ;)